# Why am i getting location details in local language?

Tags: android, locale, geocoding

I am getting the `AddressLine` in local language(Hindi).

I was using `Locale.getDefault()`, thought that might be the reason.

But even after changing it to `Locale.ENGLISH` I get the same result.

```
List<Address> addresses = null;
try {
    Geocoder gCoder = new Geocoder(c, Locale.ENGLISH);
    addresses = gCoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
    Address addr = addresses.get(0);

    String addressLine = addr.getAddressLine(0);

    }catch{
        }
```

I expected it to give the value in **English**, if that's not possible, return **null** so that i can go with something else other than **AddressLine**.

**EDIT:**

Tried this

```
Locale mLocale = new Locale("en");
Log.d("Display language = ", "" + mLocale.getDisplayLanguage());
Geocoder gCoder = new Geocoder(c, mLocale);

LogCat: Display language = English
```

But i get the same result.

Thank You

Comment: try `Locale.US` instead of `Locale.ENGLISH`

Comment: I get the same result :(

Comment: @Archie.bpgc Did you manage to find out what's going on? I am recently seeing a similar issue where I request the reverse geocoding lookup in Locale.US/ Locale.English and receive localized fields especially problematic for me the "country code"?

Comment: @saberrider I am seeing the same problem. With `Locale.English` I get the name of the city of Vienna sometimes in English and sometimes in the local language ("Wien"). Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: @MarkusPenguin I'm struggling with the same issue. Did you find any solution?

Comment: Did anyone find the solution for this problem?